# How can I make git difftool to use gvim (gvimdiff)?

Tags: git, vim, git-diff, vimdiff

There seems to have been a change in git which makes it no longer work correctly with gvim as the diff tool.  Specifically, I always used to use the gvim -geometry flag to maximize the window.  Now, I end up with one of the windows blank (empty/zero line file).

Comment: We would have needed your actual git config to help. Also, when you speculate about a "change in git", it would make sense to mention the Git version(s), right?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I found the answer.  In order to work correctly, gvim must stay in the foreground and NOT fork a new process as usual.  This is accomplished by using the `-f` or `--nofork` flag when starting gvim (or gvimdiff).

I have now setup the following alias which works:

```
alias gitdg='git difftool --noprompt --extcmd="gvim -d --nofork -geometry 220x80+2000+40" '
```

Please be careful to note the placement of single- vs. double-quotes to keep the zsh shell happy.

I used the gvim option `-geometry` to configure the diff windows to have 220 lines x 80 columns. The "+2000+40" means the upper left corner of window to be offset of 2000 pixels horizontally and 80 pixels vertically from the top-left corner of all monitors, so the window appears on the right monitor of my 2-monitor setup.  Try setting it to `-geometry 160x40+60+20` to see the effect of changes.

Comment: You can also substitute "gvimdiff" in place of "gvim -d" if you wish.

Comment: On Windows Server 2012R2 I was able to use 
`git difftool --no-prompt --extcmd="'C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\gvim' -d -f"` 
the above got me to where I needed to be.  Thx.

Answer (score 5):

On Windows Server 2012R2, adding the following to my .gitconfig worked for me as well.  My experience was that the -d and -f were not necessary for my setup.  Even though this is Windows, assure you use forward slashes '/' for the path information.

```
[alias]
    d = difftool
[diff]
    tool = gvimdiff
[difftool]
    prompt = false
[difftool "gvimdiff"]
    path = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Vim/vim81/gvim.exe"
```

Sample Run ...

```
c:\>git d index.html
```

I also discovered I had defined a function for diffexpr in my _vimrc, this needed commented out like so ...

```
"set diffexpr=MyDiff()
```

... which allows the 'new' built-in diff to work within gVim.  With those changes, everything worked in gui vim.