# Using `gvim diff` instead of `vimdiff`

Tags: git, vim

I use Windows, so I do not have a terminal with good color support. Because of this, I want to use `gvim` for my diff tool.

However, I'm not sure how to set it up so that git uses it by default, and the only way I know how to use gvimdiff is to call `gvim -d`.

How would I get it set up properly?

Comment: I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53541930/480454) on Windows with Git using gvimdiff.

Answer (score 2):

#### Fugitive.vim

As an alternative, have you thought about using [fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive)?

> I'm not going to lie to you; fugitive.vim may very well be the best
>   Git wrapper of all time.

There is a an excellent [Vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/) episode, [Fugitive.vim - resolving merge conflicts with vimdiff](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/fugitive-vim-resolving-merge-conflicts-with-vimdiff/), by Drew Neil. This is part of a series on fugitive.

To use fugitive you can just run `:Gdiff` to get `git diff` of the current file. Bonus: you can use fugative.vim inside of GVim, MacVim, or whatever Vim gui you have.

Fugitive has a lot more to offer than just being a diff tool so make sure you read the documentation and/or check out the vimcasts.

#### `git difftool`

Use `git difftool` and pick gvimdiff. e.g. `git difftool --tool gvimdiff` instead of `git diff`. For more help see [`git difftool --help`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool) and `git difftool --tool-help`. You may also want to look into setting `diff.guitool` or `diff.tool` config options.

Comment: I like both options! I will give fugitive a go but I still want to set it up as asked in the question. Thanks for the suggestion though!